# Zepto Mobile Framework - Events in Browser

Tags: jquery, mobile, zepto

At the moment I am testing this Zepto Mobile Javascript framework.

I downloaded the examples but strangely enough I am noticing that on chrome desktop browser, when clicking on the item that triggers a sub menu (by a webkit slide effect) is not working.

I uploaded the same files on my hosting server and tested out the same page on my iphone it works perfectly fine.

I checked the code and noticed that Zepto is doing binding of a touchstart event where I think it does not work on a desktop browser.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document.body).bind('touchstart', function(e){
  var now = Date.now(), delta = now - (touch.last || now);
  touch.target = parentIfText(e.touches[0].target);
  touchTimeout && clearTimeout(touchTimeout);
  touch.x1 = e.touches[0].pageX;
  touch.y1 = e.touches[0].pageY;
  if (delta > 0 && delta <= 250) touch.isDoubleTap = true;
  touch.last = now;
}).bind('touchmove', function(e){
  touch.x2 = e.touches[0].pageX;
  touch.y2 = e.touches[0].pageY;
}).bind('touchend', function(e){
  if (touch.isDoubleTap) {
    $(touch.target).trigger('doubleTap');
    touch = {};
  } else if (touch.x2 > 0 || touch.y2 > 0) {
    (Math.abs(touch.x1 - touch.x2) > 30 || Math.abs(touch.y1 - touch.y2) > 30)  &&
      $(touch.target).trigger('swipe') &&
      $(touch.target).trigger('swipe' + (swipeDirection(touch.x1, touch.x2, touch.y1,     touch.y2)));
    touch.x1 = touch.x2 = touch.y1 = touch.y2 = touch.last = 0;
  } else if ('last' in touch) {
    touchTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
      touchTimeout = null;
      $(touch.target).trigger('tap')
      touch = {};
    }, 250);
  }
});
  });
```

Does anyone tested Zepto (Iphone Example) on Chrome/Safari and he can managed to access the submenu?

This is the example URL - https://github.com/madrobby/zepto/blob/master/examples/iphone/index.html

Zepto Demo Package URL - 
https://github.com/madrobby/zepto

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between touch and click events. Touch events will not work in a desktop browser, but are much faster on mobile clients, whereas clicks are better for desktop browsers. You should use them accordingly.